# Несколько #include в одной строке

Tags: c, gcc, include

Можно ли отобразить (записать) несколько ***#include*** в одной строчке кода?

Например так:

```
#include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h> #include <time.h>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532309/multiple-preprocessor-directives-on-one-line-in-c

Comment: Нет. Только одна директива в одной строке (@alexolut, зачем отправлять читать английский, если люди спрашивают на русском?)

Comment: @avp когда нет времени ответить по-русски, считаю, ссылка на английский источник может пригодиться. Вы так не думаете?

Comment: @alexolut Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии–ссылки) – вредны. Такой  ответ может лишь демотивировать кого–либо опубликовать развернутый ответ.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky если никто не напишет в ближайшее время, я сам разберу этот вопрос и опубликую ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Директива препроцессора начинается с `#`, заканчивается концом строки (если только последним символом перед концом строки не стоит `\` - символ продолжения на следующую строку.

Результат: **нельзя**. Ибо такой директивы нет...